# Can we apply Egorov's theorem?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We have the following example : for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in [0,1[$ we define : $f_n(x)=x^n$.

We know that $\forall x \in [0,1[$, $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $f\equiv 0$. However its not uniformly convergent.

Now, I was wondering if we can apply Egorov's theorem to find a measurable set big enough where $f_n$ is uniformly convergent ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Note that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f\equiv 0$ on $[0,1-\epsilon].$

Comment: @mfl I thought about writing the same thing in acomment too, but that way the question would spend eternity in the "unanswered questions" queue.

Comment: @user159517 You have given a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to be outrageously creative here. For $0<\delta <1$, we find $$|f_{n}(x)| \leq \delta^{n} \to 0, \quad x \in [0,\delta].$$
I also wanted to point out that there is an issue with your argumentation: on $[0,1)$, the limiting function of the sequence $(f_n)$ is indeed continuous (while it isn't on $[0,1]$). However, the convergence is still not uniform as $\sup_{x\in[0,1)} |f_n(x)| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)|$.

Comment: For Borel's measure we will have $\beta([1-\delta,1[)\le \delta$ so the big measurable set will be $[0,\delta]$ indeed. And also you are right with the argument of the limiting function ! It is similar with Dini' results !

Comment: My mistake : we to need to consider $]1-\delta,1[$